# Re-sync offsets with MirrorMaker2

Tags: apache-kafka-mirrormaker

MirrorMaker2 (strimzi:0.22.1-kafka-2.7.0) is configured to do one directional mirroring from broker A to B with group offset sync enabled:

```
sync.group.offsets.enabled: true
sync.group.offsets.interval.seconds: 30
```

The setup was working fine to a point when one of the nodes on source broker A became unavailable for some time. Since then the offsets stopped syncing, and the lag only grew on the destination broker B for the topics that were only consumed from the source broker A. So the problem now is that group offsets stopped being synced.

What was tried so far:

- restarting the task (no effect)
- restarting the MirrorMaker2 (no effect)
- resetting offsets on the destination broker B (the offsets were not syncing, lag was just growing)
- removing group id from the destination broker B (the group ID was not re-created on the destination)
- removing the topic (topic was then re-created and not consumer group nor offsets started to sync)
- disabling offset sync and enabling it again (no effect)

Seems like the broken consumer groups are still present in internal topics and prevent those to be re-create/re-synced.

Is there any way to re-sync particular topics or groupId without re-creating the broker?